# In Kotlin, why does mutableListOf return an instance of java.util.ArrayList, while listOf returns an instance of java.util.Arrays$ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, kotlin, arraylist

In Kotlin, the mutableListOf method returns an instance of java.util.ArrayList that implements Kotlin's MutableList interface.

Now, the listOf method returns an instance of java.util.Arrays$ArrayList that implements Kotlin's List interface.

From what I understand, List and MutableList are just meant to be two different "views" of ArrayList, immutable and mutable. Why do they map to seemingly different ArrayList classes when they are, as juxtaposing interfaces, what defines the behavior and use of an ArrayList in Kotlin?

What is the difference between java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Arrays$ArrayList? I couldn't find anything about the latter in the java docs. This question stems from what this code outputs in the console:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val mutableList = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3)

println( list.javaClass )           // class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList 
println( mutableList.javaClass )    // class java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: Programming Kotlin: Create Elegant, Expressive, and Performant JVM and Android Applications by Venkat Subramaniam. Chapter 5, Using Collections. "Kotlin provides two different views for lists, sets, and maps: the read-only or
immutable view, and the read-write or mutable view."

Comment: Aha, I got confused by your wording, sorry. You seem to have a misunderstanding about interfaces.

Comment: I believe I do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why do they map to seemingly different ArrayList classes when they are, as juxtaposing interfaces?

Interfaces don't "map to" classes. Interfaces specifies a set of requirements. If a class implements an interface, it means that it *meets all the requirements specified in that interface*.

`listOf` returns an object that is capable of doing all the things listed in the `List` interface. That's what it means for a function to be declared to "return a `List`" Similarly, `mutableListOf` returns an object that is capable of doing all the things listed in the `MutableList` interface.

It does not matter which specific type of object that the methods return, as long as they are capable of doing the things specified in the interface. Which specific kind they return, i.e. `listOf(...)::class` and `mutableListOf()::class` are *implementation details*. Because they are implementation detail, you should not take it as "absolute truth" and say things like "`listOf` returns an `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`". In fact, it doesn't. At the time of writing, `listOf<Integer>()::class` is `class kotlin.collections.EmptyList`.

Anyway, `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is an immutable list. It's a private inner class in `java.util.Arrays`. You'd usually see this class in Java when you do `Arrays.asList`, which serves a similar purpose to `listOf`, but again, this is an implementation detail. On the other hand, `java.util.ArrayList` is mutable.

Though `listOf` could have been designed to return an `ArrayList` (this is totally fine), and its mutable nature could be hidden behind the immutable `List` interface (which `ArrayList` also implements), it could be *speculated* that returning an `Arrays$ArrayList` is preferable because 1) it does not create a copy of the array you passed to `listOf`. 2) It *does* implement `List`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer actually cleared up a lot more for me than just my question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is a nested class inside `Arrays` class. The main difference between `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` and `java.util.ArrayList` is that the first has fixed length while the latter's length can grow. Both lists are backed by arrays.

`java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` will also be return type of `Arrays.asList` which used to create immutable list from an array.

That is the reason, why `MutableList` inherits from `java.util.ArrayList` and `List` on the other hand inherits from `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` since it is immutable.